# How to set json data to list view?

Tags: android, android-listview

I tried to add json data to listview.But i don't know how to add the json data to list adapter.

```
try {
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("restaurants");



    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String restName = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(restName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){//this name is predefined name.
        String address = jsonChildNode.optString("address");
        String mobile = jsonChildNode.optString("mobile");
        String direction = "Direction: "+jsonChildNode.optString("direction");
        String bestTime = "Best time to visite: "+jsonChildNode.optString("bestTime");
        String food = jsonChildNode.optString("food");
        String dress = jsonChildNode.optString("dress");
        String priceRange = "Price Range: "+jsonChildNode.optString("priceRange");
        String rate = jsonChildNode.optString("Rate");
        String comment = "Price Range: "+jsonChildNode.optString("comment");


        map.put("restName",restName);
        map.put("address",address);
        map.put("mobile",mobile);
        map.put("direction",direction);
        map.put("bestTime",bestTime);
        map.put("food",food);
        map.put("dress",dress);
        map.put("priceRange",priceRange);
        map.put("rate",rate);
        map.put("comment",comment);

        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        mylist.add(map);
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }


} catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error..." + e.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mylist);
//  list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Can anyone tel me how to set this data to list view.?

Comment: you can find the answer here => [Android Populate ListView from JSON – Example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html)

Comment: U should use custom adapter.

Comment: have you solve your issue? @anuruddhika

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Your doing **reversely**. **declear** the `arraylist` before **for loop** and **declear** the `HashMap` inside the **for loop** .

```
mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();           

    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("restaurants");



    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String restName = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(restName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){//this name is predefined name.
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String address = jsonChildNode.optString("address");
        //So on


        map.put("restName",restName);
        //So on

        mylist.add(map);
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Comment: @anuruddhika then again you initilize inside if condition then that will again clear or reinitilize every time loop running.

Comment: @anuruddhika hmm k where did you populat the `mylist` to listview code. can you post that code.

Comment: I think that should be the problem. i didn't use adapter class here. i mention is as a comment in my code.

Comment: @anuruddhika you should use custom adapter. what are all data you need to display in listview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44864/discussion-between-anuruddhika-and-tamilan)

Answer (score 0):

## google-gson

I would use gson for this. Check [the gson project website](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for more details on how. This is an example for object serialisation/deserialisation:

Object Examples

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}
```

(Serialization)

```
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}

Note that you can not serialize objects with circular references since that will result in infinite recursion.

(Deserialization)

```
BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
```

==> obj2 is just like obj